# R. as.numeric. 0 unequal 0

Tags: r

I need help with the function as.numeric in R.
The data frame I'm working with contains factors with following structure:

```
data[, 28] <- as.character(data[, 28])
attributes(data)$variable.labels[28] <- "[text]"
data[, 28] <- factor(data[, 28], levels=c("A0","A1","A2","A3","A4","A5"),labels=c("Stimme überhaupt nicht zu", "", "", "", "", "Stimme voll und ganz zu"))
```

Now if use the following command:

```
df3[,x] <- as.numeric(as.factor(df3[,x]))
```

A0 (levels) which should ideally represent zero (0) changes to 1. 
As far as I know this could be due to the nature of as.numeric creating a vector starting with 1. Hence 0 isn't included. 
Now my question is how  to change the factor to numeric with an output containing zero (0) as a numeric value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Factors in R are represented internally as integers and the first factor is 1.

If you want your factors to start at zero, you just need to use

```
df3[,x] <- as.numeric(as.factor(df3[,x])) -1
```